# Generate sets for cross-validation

Tags: r

How to split automatically a matrix using R for 5-fold cross-validation?
I actually want to generate the 5 sets of (test_matrix_indices, train matrix_indices).

Comment: Please don't mix answers into your question. This gets confusing. If you want to answer your own question, then please do so in a new answer.

Comment: For K fold cross-validation you have to merge K-1 subsets as training set and leave one as test (repeat it K times), so this is not complete solution for your problem.

Comment: I have put my answer into the answers section.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
f_K_fold <- function(Nobs,K=5){
    rs <- runif(Nobs)
    id <- seq(Nobs)[order(rs)]
    k <- as.integer(Nobs*seq(1,K-1)/K)
    k <- matrix(c(0,rep(k,each=2),Nobs),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
    k[,1] <- k[,1]+1
    l <- lapply(seq.int(K),function(x,k,d) 
                list(train=d[!(seq(d) %in% seq(k[x,1],k[x,2]))],
                     test=d[seq(k[x,1],k[x,2])]),k=k,d=id)
   return(l)
}
```

Comment: It is an elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: Moreover, this solution can become deterministic by adding set.seed(n)

Comment: what id d? I dont get it.

Comment: Similar to [`caret::createDataPartition`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf)

Answer (score 23):

I suppose you want the matrix rows to be the cases to split. Then all you need is `sample` and `split` :

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(1000),ncol=5)
id <- sample(1:5,nrow(X),replace=TRUE)
ListX <- split(x,id) # gives you a list with the 5 matrices
X[id==2,] # gives you the second matrix
```

I'd work with the list, as it allows you to do something like :

```
names(ListX) <- c("Train1","Train2","Train3","Test1","Test2")
mean(ListX$Train3)
```

which makes for code that's easier to read, and keeps you from creating tons of matrices in your workspace. You're bound to mess up if you put the matrices individually in your workspace. Use lists!

In case you want the test matrix to be smaller or larger than the other ones, use the `prob` argument of `sample` :

```
id <- sample(1:5,nrow(X),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.3))
```

gives you a test matrix that's double the size of the train matrices.

In case you want to determine the exact number of cases, `sample` and `prob` aren't the best options. You could use a trick like :

```
indices <- rep(1:5,c(100,20,20,20,40))
id <- sample(indices)
```

to get matrices with respectively 100, 20, ... and 40 cases.

Comment: +1 for split - i'd actually been wondering about generating matrices for crossvalidation myself, and this is perfect.

Comment: joris great code thanks.  

isn't the idea with cross validation that you loop through all sets and use each group as testing data at least once which would defeat the purpose of using the list and naming it like you do?

Comment: @appleLover The use of lists is merely to avoid having to generate individual matrices in your workspace. It's to keep everything together. There's multiple approaches to cross validation and bootstrapping, and depending on the approach you'll need different corrections on your statistics. I just gave a method to create those matrices in an organized way.

Comment: aren't the folds supposed to be of equal size in cross-validation? According to the code above `table(id)` returns variable sizes for different folds.

Comment: @Berkan That depends on the method. With bigger datasets it's not uncommon to have a small training set and a large evaluation set. That way you mimick better the effect of getting a (relatively) small sample from a (potentially) infinitely large population.

Answer (score 4):

Solution without split:

```
set.seed(7402313)
X <- matrix(rnorm(999), ncol=3)
k <- 5 # number of folds

# Generating random indices 
id <- sample(rep(seq_len(k), length.out=nrow(X)))
table(id)
# 1  2  3  4  5 
# 67 67 67 66 66 

# lapply over them:
indicies <- lapply(seq_len(k), function(a) list(
    test_matrix_indices = which(id==a),
    train_matrix_indices = which(id!=a)
))
str(indicies)
# List of 5
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ test_matrix_indices : int [1:67] 12 13 14 17 18 20 23 28 41 45 ...
#   ..$ train_matrix_indices: int [1:266] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ test_matrix_indices : int [1:67] 4 19 31 36 47 53 58 67 83 89 ...
#   ..$ train_matrix_indices: int [1:266] 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ test_matrix_indices : int [1:67] 5 8 9 30 32 35 37 56 59 60 ...
#   ..$ train_matrix_indices: int [1:266] 1 2 3 4 6 7 10 11 12 13 ...
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ test_matrix_indices : int [1:66] 1 2 3 6 21 24 27 29 33 34 ...
#   ..$ train_matrix_indices: int [1:267] 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 ...
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ test_matrix_indices : int [1:66] 7 10 11 15 16 22 25 26 40 42 ...
#   ..$ train_matrix_indices: int [1:267] 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 12 13 ...
```

But you could return matrices too:

```
matrices <- lapply(seq_len(k), function(a) list(
    test_matrix = X[id==a, ],
    train_matrix = X[id!=a, ]
))
str(matrices)
List of 5
 # $ :List of 2
  # ..$ test_matrix : num [1:67, 1:3] -1.0132 -1.3657 -0.3495 0.6664 0.0762 ...
  # ..$ train_matrix: num [1:266, 1:3] -0.65 0.797 0.689 0.484 0.682 ...
 # $ :List of 2
  # ..$ test_matrix : num [1:67, 1:3] 0.484 0.418 -0.622 0.996 0.414 ...
  # ..$ train_matrix: num [1:266, 1:3] -0.65 0.797 0.689 0.682 0.186 ...
 # $ :List of 2
  # ..$ test_matrix : num [1:67, 1:3] 0.682 0.812 -1.111 -0.467 0.37 ...
  # ..$ train_matrix: num [1:266, 1:3] -0.65 0.797 0.689 0.484 0.186 ...
 # $ :List of 2
  # ..$ test_matrix : num [1:66, 1:3] -0.65 0.797 0.689 0.186 -1.398 ...
  # ..$ train_matrix: num [1:267, 1:3] 0.484 0.682 0.473 0.812 -1.111 ...
 # $ :List of 2
  # ..$ test_matrix : num [1:66, 1:3] 0.473 0.212 -2.175 -0.746 1.707 ...
  # ..$ train_matrix: num [1:267, 1:3] -0.65 0.797 0.689 0.484 0.682 ...
```

Then you could use `lapply` to get results:

```
lapply(matrices, function(x) {
     m <- build_model(x$train_matrix)
     performance(m, x$test_matrix)
})
```

---

Edit: compare to Wojciech's solution:

```
f_K_fold <- function(Nobs, K=5){
    id <- sample(rep(seq.int(K), length.out=Nobs))
    l <- lapply(seq.int(K), function(x) list(
         train = which(x!=id),
         test  = which(x==id)
    ))
    return(l)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit : Thanks for your answers.
I have found the following solution (http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/fichiers/fr_Tanagra_Validation_Croisee_Suite.pdf) :

```
n <- nrow(mydata)
K <- 5
size <- n %/% K
set.seed(5)
rdm <- runif(n)
ranked <- rank(rdm)
block <- (ranked-1) %/% size+1
block <- as.factor(block)
```

Then I use :

```
for (k in 1:K) {
    matrix_train<-matrix[block!=k,]
    matrix_test<-matrix[block==k,]
    [Algorithm sequence]
    }
```

in order to generate the adequate sets for each iterations.

However this solution can omit one individual for tests. I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Below does the trick without having to create separate data.frames/matrices, all you need to do is to keep an integer sequnce, `id` that stores the shuffled indices for each fold.

```
X <- read.csv('data.csv')

k = 5 # number of folds
fold_size <-nrow(X)/k
indices <- rep(1:k,rep(fold_size,k))
id <- sample(indices, replace = FALSE) # random draws without replacement

log_models <- new.env(hash=T, parent=emptyenv()) 
for (i in 1:k){
  train <- X[id != i,]
  test <- X[id == i,]
  # run algorithm, e.g. logistic regression
  log_models[[as.character(i)]] <- glm(outcome~., family="binomial", data=train)
}
```

Comment: Note that when nrow(X) is not a multiple of k then some samples get  dropped.

Answer (score 0):

The `sperrorest` package provides this ability. You can choose between a random split (`partition.cv()`), a spatial split (`partition.kmeans()`), or a split based on factor levels (`partition.factor.cv()`). The latter is currently only available in the [Github](https://github.com/pat-s/sperrorest) version.

Example:

```
library(sperrorest)
data(ecuador)

## non-spatial cross-validation:
resamp <- partition.cv(ecuador, nfold = 5, repetition = 1:1)

# first repetition, second fold, test set indices:
idx <- resamp[['1']][[2]]$test

# test sample used in this particular repetition and fold:
ecuador[idx , ]
```

If you have a spatial data set (with coords), you can also visualize your generated folds

```
# this may take some time...
plot(resamp, ecuador)
```

[image]

Cross-validation can then be performed using `sperrorest()` (sequential) or `parsperrorest()` (parallel).